# List Foreach returning booleans

Tags: c#, list, foreach, boolean

I have a simple list of integers:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
```

Is there any way how to check a constraint like this :

```
bool result = ints.ForEach(x=>x > 0);
```

so the result would be true if each number in the list is bigger than 0 and false if any number from the list would be less than 0.

Any idaes?

Thanks

Comment: What's the language again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`IEnumerable<T>.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) extension method, which returns true if all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
bool result = ints.All(x => x > 0); // true if all items are > 0
```

Comment: If this is of interest for anyone: If `ints` was empty, `All()` would return `true`.